# Counting the number of months, quarters and counts from a cell using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, datatable, stringr

A cell from an example from a give data-frame (df$desc) contains the following : `Month:High=Mar_May  Low=Jul_Oct | Qtr:High=Q3`

How do I generate the fields(Required Table) from the cell i.e given above -

Required table:

```
Fields                 Count
Month Count               4
Quarter Count             1
Month High Count          2
Month Low Count           2
Quarter High Count        1
Quarter Low Count         0
```

Logic:

1. Month Count - 4   ; as we have 4 months on the cell i.e Mar,May,Jul and Oct.
2. Quarter Count - 1 ; as we have 1 quarter on the cell i.e. Q3
3. Month High Count-  2 ; as we have 2 months on the cell which is set as High
4. Qtr High Count-  1 ; as we have 1 Quarter on the cell which is set as High
5. Month Low Count-  2 ; as we have 2 months on the cell which is set as Low
6. Qtr Low Count-  0 ; as we have 0 Quarter on the cell which is set as Low

Comment: Can you explain the logic to arrive at each of the figures in the results?  It's really not clear

Comment: @Hobo recheck the question, I have edited it with the logic

Comment: Thanks @InVinci, that's clearer.  Can you have any number of months and quarters for each term (e.g. could you have `Month:High=Jan_Feb_Jun_Sep Low=Aug`)?

Comment: Yes, @Hobo any combinations may exist as it is dependent on any input dataset and it may have any sort of possible variation. The logic needs to be robust in order to automate every corner case.

Comment: In that case the cell looks like : (Month:High=Jan_Feb_Jun_Sep Low=Aug |)
and the other situation the cell looks like : ( | Qtr:High=Q2)

Comment: @Hobo hopefully the use case is now completely clear?

Comment: Yep, clear now.  Just thinking about how I'd approach it now I understand the problem :)

Comment: Ya, I was also thinking about the same. I feel we can create default lists one for Months i.e (Jan:Dec), one for quarters i.e. (Q1:Q4), and one for (High,Low), and then we may use stringr | regex. What do you think?

Comment: It would be helpful to understand if you could provide a reproducible example using `dput(head(df))` along with expected output for those rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this seems to work.  It's quite a bit longer than it needs to be, just so you can look at each transformation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(desc=c(
    'Month:High=Mar_May  Low=Jul_Oct | Qtr:High=Q3',
    'Month:High=Jan_Feb_Jun_Sep Low=Aug |',
    ' | Qtr:High=Q2',
    ' | Qtr:Low=Q2_Q3'
))

df %>% 
  # Split the month from the quarter, using the pipe
  separate(desc, into = c('MonthPart', 'QuarterPart'), sep = '\\|', remove = FALSE) %>%
  
  # Get the high and low parts for month and quarter
  # These will be NA where the values are missing
  mutate(HighMonth = str_extract(MonthPart, '(?<=High=)[^ ]+'),
         LowMonth = str_extract(MonthPart, '(?<=Low=)[^ ]+'),
         HighQuarter = str_extract(QuarterPart, '(?<=High=)[^ ]+'),
         LowQuarter = str_extract(QuarterPart, '(?<=Low=)[^ ]+')) %>%
  
  # Work out the number of months/quarters using the length of the string
  # e.g. each month is 3 characters plus the _ (add 1 because the last month
  # or quarter has no _)
  mutate(HighMonthCount = (nchar(HighMonth) + 1) / 4,
         LowMonthCount = (nchar(LowMonth) + 1) / 4,
         HighQuarterCount = (nchar(HighQuarter) + 1) / 3,
         LowQuarterCount = (nchar(LowQuarter) + 1) / 3) %>%
  
  # NAs to 0
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~if_else(is.na(.), 0, .)) %>% 
  
  # Work out total month and quarter counts
  mutate(MonthCount = HighMonthCount + LowMonthCount,
         QuarterCount = HighQuarterCount + LowQuarterCount) %>% 
  
  # Just keep the columns of interest
  select(desc, contains('Count')) %>% 
  
  # Pivot to required format
  pivot_longer(!desc, names_to = 'Fields', values_to = 'Count')
```

Comment: Let me try your snippet @Hobo